# numpy.ndarray as Dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am storing numpy.ndarray as a value of a dictionary. My dictionary looks like:

```
{0: array([[ 1,  0, -1],
   [ 0, -1,  0],
   [ 1,  0,  0]])}
```

But when I am trying to find out if array exists in the dictionary using the following command

```
S = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)
if S in myDict.values():
   print "something"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have seen some one who have this problem, but their situation is different. Can anybody help me get ouf it?

At least any suggestion to check if a value exist in Dictionary? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What should be the command exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `np.array_equal`:

```
S = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)
if any(np.array_equal(S, i) for i in myDict.values()):
   print "Yes!"
else:
   print "Sorry. No."

[OUTPUT]
Sorry. No.
```

Comment: @vessilli, Glad I could help. If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? (After the time limit) Thank you. And good luck.

Comment: Why not!! I will do it after the time limit.